# Password validation failed from ASP.NET 4.8 library

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

Platform: ASP.NET Core 7.0, Visual Studio 2022, C++, ASP.NET 4.8

We have an ASP.NET Core Web API in which Entity Framework has been implemented which uses user table to store user name and hash password

We have another C++ application which validates user login name and password from same user table using that ASP.NET 4.8 framework library.

My problem is that when we generate hash password using the ASP.NET 4.8 library and store this hashed password in the user table, the user name and password is successfully validated by both application.

When the hashed password is generated by the ASP.NET Core Web API and stored in the user table, the user name and password is successfully validated by the ASP.NET Core Web API, but the C++ application is failing.

Please suggest how validate user name and password from C++ when password id is generated by the ASP.NET Core Web API.

Thanks in advance,
Vijay

Code to validate password using ASP.NET 4.8:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;

public bool VerifyHashPasswd(string hashedPassword, string plainPassword)
{
      var hasher = new Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.PasswordHasher();
      var successResult = hasher.VerifyHashedPassword(hashedPassword, plainPassword);
      return successResult.ToString().Equals("success", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
}
```

Code to validate password using asp.net core where function `CheckPasswordAsync` is being used to check password.

```
public class AppUserManager : UserManager<TableUserInfo>
{
    // UserInfoStore store2= new UserInfoStore;

    public AppUserManager(IUserStore<TableUserInfo> store,
                          IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor,
                          IPasswordHasher<TableUserInfo> passwordHasher,
                          IEnumerable<IUserValidator<TableUserInfo>> userValidators,
                          IEnumerable<IPasswordValidator<TableUserInfo>> passwordValidators,
                          ILookupNormalizer keyNormalizer,
                          IdentityErrorDescriber errors,
                          IServiceProvider services,
                          ILogger<UserManager<TableUserInfo>> logger)
    : base(store, optionsAccessor, passwordHasher, userValidators, passwordValidators, keyNormalizer, errors, services, logger)
    {
    }


    public override async Task<bool> CheckPasswordAsync(TableUserInfo user, string password)
    {
        ThrowIfDisposed();

        var passwordStore = GetPasswordStore();

        if (user == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        var result = await VerifyPasswordAsync(passwordStore, user, password).ConfigureAwait(false);

        var success = result != PasswordVerificationResult.Failed;

        return success;
    }

    private IUserPasswordStore<TableUserInfo> GetPasswordStore()
    {
        var cast = Store as IUserPasswordStore<TableUserInfo>;

        if (cast == null)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException("StoreNotIUserPasswordStore");
        }

        return cast;
    }
}
```

I have found solution. Solution is

```
public class UserInfo : IdentityUser<int>
{
    public string? FirstName { get; set; }
    public string? LastName { get; set; }
    //public override string Id { get; set; }
    // public  void setId(int i) { Id=i.ToString(); }
    public string? RefreshToken { get; set; }
    public DateTime? RefreshTokenExpiryTime { get; set; }
}

public string VerifyHashPasswd(string hashedPassword, string plainPassword)
{
    UserInfo t = new UserInfo();
    var hasher = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.PasswordHasher<TableUserInfo>();
    var successResult = hasher.VerifyHashedPassword(t, hashedPassword, plainPassword);
    return successResult.ToString();//.Equals("success", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

}
```

Comment: It will be next to impossible for anyone to provide any meaningful input without seeing any code at all .....

Comment: Also: if you create the same user with the exact same password in both your .NET 4.8 and your .NET Core 7 library - do they end up being the same values in the database? If not, then there's some difference in how the password is hashed - find that difference and fix it

Comment: Hi marc_s, thanks for the reply. Hash password is being generated from ASP.NET core identity framework. From asp.net 4.8 password is being validated using function VerifyHashPasswd(...) as code has been posted in the question.